# Storing Array or IList in another IList data model

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I cannot seem to find the best practice or the best mechanism for structuring and consuming data for my MVVM Xamarin form application. This could be a simple misunderstanding on how to attack the problem, but I am not certain.

I have tried using IEnumerable, IList, and a simple array for a multi-dimensional Data (binding?) but I am pretty new to MVVM so, I may be approaching this wrong.

This is for a Xamarin.Forms Android app, so using the MySQL type data bindings do not work (since you cannot store in a database). So using these data classes is the correct way, but I do not know how to structure relational data.
Each Belt can have MANY videos, buttons, and other content.

I gone through the Xamarin examples on this, but none address relational data that is shipped with the app.

```
// Trying to use an aray
public IList<BeltContent> BeltContents { get; private set; }
public BeltData()
    {
        // Bringing it all together
        BeltContents = new List<BeltContent>();

        BeltContents.Add(new BeltContent
        {
            BeltName = "White",
            VideoContent = {
                  "https://url-to-my-video01", 
                  "https://url-to-my-video01" }
        });

    }


//Trying to use an IList to initialize inside

public IList<BeltContent> BeltContents { get; private set; }
public Ilist<VideoContent> VideoContents {get; private set; }
public BeltData()
    {
        // Bringing it all together
        BeltContents = new List<BeltContent>();
        VideoContents = new List<VideoContent>();

        BeltContents.Add(new BeltContent
        {
            BeltName = "White",
            VideoContent = VideoContents.Add(new VideoContent
               {
                   VideoName = "SomeName",
                   VideoUri = "Https://some-url-to-video"
               },
               {
                  //etc
               }
        });

    }
```

I do also have data models for these
NOTE: The comments for the BeltContent for other routes I have attempted.
Added as comments to consolidate the code

```
// The Data Model for videos (note they all follow this pattern)
public class VideoContent
{
    public string VideoName { get; set; }

    public string VideoUri { get; set; }
}


// Full content for the data model
public class BeltContent
{

    public string BeltName { get; set; }

    public string BeltDescription { get; set; }

    // public IEnumerable<VideoContent> VideoContent {get; set;}
    // public string[] VideoContent {get; set; }
    // public IList<VideoContent> VideoContent {get; set;} 

    public VideoContent VideoContent {get; set; }

    public ButtonResourceUri ButtonResourceUri { get; set; }

    public WrittenContent WrittenContent { get; set; }

}
```

I was hoping that I could use a multi-dimensional array of sorts or IList to store nesting data.

Comment: I think your basic question is "How do I design my data model?"  That's a pretty broad question and difficult to answer on SO.  Is there some specific part of the design that is giving you problems?  The fact that this is a Xamarin app or MVVM is really irrelevant to the design of your model.

Comment: I can try to clarify in the question above, but I am not sure how to describe it. I know how to create data models, I just do not know how to reference and/or consume and/or structure that data in a meaningful way when **not** using SQL

Comment: "relational data that is shipped with the app" - why don't you supply a pre-populated SQLite db with your app?

Comment: I would love to do that though most of the tutorials and/or discussions on creating SQlite DBs do not show how to initialize them with data, like the ASP.Net/MVC tutorials/docs do. I also seem to recall hearing that you should not do that due to the ease of the user reading your database directly

Comment: there are many third party SQLite tools you can use to create dbs and populate with data manually or via import.  Google "sqlite manager"

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer, because it was too long. Maybe it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the comments of your post I'm trying a blind shot...

As i was new to Xamarin (coming from Windows Forms and Server) this was a problem for me too. How to store? The big ORMs dont work...?!

It's relatively easy - you are on Xamarin with it's own rules. There are lot of solutions for Xamarin related problems, i'll try to show my standard solution.

- Create the Xamarin-Project
- Create a class library (preferable in .Net Standard)
- Open the Nuget Package Manager for the class library
- Get yourself the "SQLite-Net Extensions" Package
- Package Name: SQLiteNetExtensions
- I don't think you need some MVVM packages for SQLiteExtensions
- There's a pretty nice tutorial on [this blog](https://www.codejourney.net/2017/05/sqlite-net-extensions-many-to-many-relationships/) on how to init the database model and how to read / write data
- The initial database has to be copied as file-include >in every platform independent project

  With PCLStorage or something else you may be able to apply this task by importing the initial database as a ressource to your xamarin app and copying the database to the needed place.

I always end up to the PCLStorage solution like [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/Adam--/a45ee0756a00bf24a847e0ddc70b0b72)

One trick with xamarin is: Try to find .net standard libraries and you should (in much cases) be able to use it on most xamarin platfoms.

The second is: Watch out for readme-files opening on nuget imports!!! These are pretty important. I used to clicked them away and forgot nearly every initialization routine. Took me hours

The third is: There are a lot of nuget-libraries that need to be installed in the base app and all platform-dependent apps. Don't forget that in cases like SQLiteExtensions - it will install platform-dependent libraries.

( Folks, don't kill me for this - I'm only trying to help ;-) )

By the way: SQLiteExtensions makes use of IList or List... If performance is a problem you can switch to the cached fork of SQLiteExtensions later (If you need to)

Comment: Also on the list now [EF Core](https://medium.com/@yostane/data-persistence-in-xamarin-using-entity-framework-core-e3a58bdee9d1)

Comment: Tried not to mention EF Core, even it may be a good solution. This should show a fast way into developing Xamarin with databases